What do I need to connect to SQL Server using Private Endpoint
I want to secure access to my data in Azure. The data should be accessible by 1 web app, that is available publicly.
So, in the app properties of the webapp I have a connections string to SQL Server, referencing it by its public url (MY_SERVER.database.windows.net)
On the server itself I have Allow Azure services access.
In order to implement security I tried to:

create a VNet
split it into 2 subnets ("sql" and "app")
create a Service Endpoint for sql subnet
limit access to SQL Server to only from the sql subnet of the VNet and disable the "Allow all Azure services" option
create a Private Endpoint for the webapp that needs to have access to data in the "app" subnet

Unfortunaly, that did not work and from logs I saw that the webapp could not bypass firewall rules of the SQL server - using webapp public IP.
So - is it required to have a private DNS Zone for "privatelink.database.windows.net"?
I would very much avoid the DN S zone due to its cost...

From my experience (using networks & IPs rather than Service Endpoints), I'd suggest that you should assign an NSG (network security group) to each subnet if you haven't already. NSGs are the 'firewalls' on subnets, determining what traffic can pass. Start with the default - intra-VNET traffic is allowed, but outside traffic is denied. Also ensure that the web app (if it's part of an Azure App Service) is actually in the VNET/subnet, in the 'networking' tab of the web app. Finally, the web app's subnet also needs access to SQL Server (it is from here that the db is accessed).

@seanb, thanks for the comment, but I am not sure how NSG would help - according to the error message the app tries to use its public IP. Or did you mean for me to try and replace Service Endpoint for SQL Server with another Private endpoint for it inside the sql subnet?

You don't need a private endpoint on the App Service.
Private endpoints there are for inbound connections only, if you wanted to connect to the App Service from within the VNET.
What you need is VNET integration.
You need to delegate a subnet for App Service and set up the integration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-vnet-integration-enable
You could create a private endpoint for the SQL though.
Then you can disable public access entirely and only connections through the private endpoint will be allowed.
You will need a private DNS zone in this case at least.
Not sure if you need one with service endpoints.

Thank you, that worked! One addition tho - both service endpoint and web app integration should be in the same subnet, at least that worked for me
